# Is it possible to enable the debug tools in an angular-cli production build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a question regarding using the debug tools in production builds:

In angular 8 it was possible to use the debug tools (ng.probe) in production builds (--prod) by not executing enableProdMode().
In angular 9 this seems to be disabled (despite the fact that one has to use ng.getComponent now).

Is there the possibility to enable the debug tools in production builds? I would need this for selenium tests.

Comment: No, that's why it is called production build :-)

Comment: It was also called production in build in ng 8...

Comment: no one should be able to see your code in production, thats why you have minified versions of your component and you cannot debug